# CreateAsyncThunk expect return value

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to convert the below code from js to typescript, however I am keep getting the error `Expected to return a value at the end of async arrow function`. Any idea what wrong this this code?

```
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/login',
  async ({ email, password }, thunkAPI) : Promise<any> => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://mock-user-auth-server.herokuapp.com/api/v1/auth',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email,
            password,
          }),
        }
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log('response', data);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
        return data;
      }
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error', e.response.data);
      thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e.response.data);
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to `return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e.response.data);` in your `catch` block.

If you call it without `return`, it will do nothing - and you will get the error you have here.

Comment: it still throw error but this time a different one : Property 'email' does not exist on type 'void'

Comment: You have not given your first input argument any type.
`async ({ email, password }: {email: string, password: string}, thunkAPI)  => {`

Answer (score 0):

You defined your return type at your arrow function (which is second parameter of createAsyncThunk function). If you return default value it will be resolve. Like this:

```
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
'users/login',
async ({ email, password }, thunkAPI) : Promise<any> => {
try {
  const response = await fetch(
    'https://mock-user-auth-server.herokuapp.com/api/v1/auth',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password,
      }),
    }
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log('response', data);
  if (response.status === 200) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
    return data;
  }
  return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(data);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Error', e.response.data);
  thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e.response.data);
}
return Promise.resolve();
}
);
```